# React Js, TypeScript, Map tags to dropdown menu

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Basically I have an array where I have all the information of iconic text and links that I will render in my sidebar, but I am unsure how to create a state to map and allowed only one item from that menu to be active at a time

like this:

[image]

And as I will have two types of menu, that is when it is closed and when it is open I am not able to solve this

my tags:

```
export const SideBarTags = [
  {
    name: 'Tutoriais',
    link: '../tutorials',
    icon: faFileAlt,
    dropdownItems: null,
  },
  {
    name: 'Avisos',
    link: '../news',
    icon: faNewspaper,
    dropdownItems: null,
  },
  {
    name: 'Serviços',
    link: '../services',
    icon: faMeteor,
    dropdownItems: [
      { name: 'Elo Boost', link: '/eloBost' },
      { name: 'Duo Boost', link: '/duoBoost' },
      { name: 'MD10', link: '/eloBost' },
      { name: 'Coaching', link: '/duoBoost' },
      { name: 'Vitóriais', link: '/duoBoost' },
    ],
  },
  {
    name: 'Carteira',
    link: '../cartcredit',
    icon: faWallet,
    dropdownItems: [
      { name: 'Histórico', link: '/history' },
      { name: 'Adicionar Crédito', link: '/add' },
    ],
  },
];
```

my tsx:

```
interface OpenedMenuTags{
  isOpen: boolean
}
const OpenedMenuTags: React.FC<OpenedMenuTags> = () {

  return(

  )
}

const Menu: React.FC<Hamburguer> = ({ isOpen }) => {
  const renderTags = () => {
    if(isOpen){
      return (
        <OpenedMenuTags isOpen={isOpen}/>
      )
    }else if(isOpen === false){
      return(
      <>
      Nothing Yet
      </>)
    }
  }
  return (
    <DashMenu open={isOpen}>
      <div className="show-hide">
        <span>
          <FontAwesomeIcon
            className="iconmenu"
            icon={faTachometerAlt}
            size="1x"
            fixedWidth
            color="white"
          />
          DashBoard
        </span>
      </div>
      <MenuList open={isOpen}>
        {isOpen?}
      </MenuList>
    </DashMenu>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

**[Edit2]** Am I the only one that can access stackblitz or what ? Haha here is the code :

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import Hello from "./Hello";
import "./style.css";

const App = () => {
  const clicked = e => {
    const dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown');
    Array.from(dropdowns).forEach(el => el.classList.remove('active'));
    e.target.parentNode.classList.add('active');
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="dropdown">
        <div onClick={event => clicked(event)}>Item 1</div>

        <div>SubItem 1</div>
        <div>SubItem 2</div>
      </div>
      <div className="dropdown">
      <div onClick={event => clicked(event)}>Item 2</div>
        <div>SubItem 3</div>
        <div>SubItem 4</div>
      </div>
      <div className="dropdown">
      <div onClick={event => clicked(event)}>Item 3</div>
        <div>SubItem 5</div>
        <div>SubItem 6</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

And here the little css:

```
.dropdown {
  height: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.active{
  height: auto;
}
```

The way it works is pretty easy. By default, menu are sized to only show the title.
By clicking on one of them, you will disable the class 'active' on every element that have the class 'dropdown' and then add the 'active' to the one you clicked.

---

**[Edit]** Does this custom solution suits your needs ? [Demo dropdowns](https://react-uq1xkx.stackblitz.io)

---

Can't you just used something like this ? [Sidenav component](https://reactjsexample.com/react-side-nav-component/)

It seems to fit your requirement, and isn't too complicated to set up. There is probably more different types of sideNav you can find, but you shouldn't try to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: The problem would not be the sidebar itself, but the dropdown, because I will have dropdown items

Comment: my side bar is ok my only problem is how can I make only one dropdown item active at a time

Comment: I added a custom solution i made, i hope it helps. If not, then precise what you do mean by 'active' please :)

Comment: I added the code so you can try it or tell me if it answer your needs